# Return private unique_ptr in public member function

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Consider the following class prototype:

```
class ObjHandler {

    std::unique_ptr<Obj> GetPtr() { return obj; }

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<Obj> obj;
};
```

This generates a compile-time error saying that the copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is deleted. Why here move semantics are not applied? Is it related to the fact that `GetPtr()` does not own the `obj` pointer? How should I implement my code (I need a member function that returns an owning pointer to the stream with the minimum overhead)?

Comment: ... return an owning pointer ...: does that mean that the original owner loses ownership?

Comment: yep, for example if the "user" doesn't want to let `obj` die when the `ObjHandler` instance goes out of scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why here move semantics are not applied?

Because `obj` is not a local variable, so the language doesn't allow it to be implicitly moved.

You can move it by using `std::move`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Obj> GetPtr() { return std::move(obj); }
```

Although if this is really what you want, I'd recommend naming the function something that makes it clear that the ownership is being transferred (i.e. that `this->obj` becomes null), e.g. `MovePtr`.

The name `GetPtr` makes it sound like it doesn't modify `this->obj` and just returns a non-owning pointer to the managed object, i.e. that its behavior is the following:

```
Obj* GetPtr() const { return obj.get(); }
```

Comment: Even though this is what the OP asks for, perhaps it's not what he *really* wants. You might want to add a few lines about what happens at the *next* call to `GetPtr()`.

Comment: If the function is implemented like that, it may be a good idea to rename it to `ConsumePtr()` to make it clear to the reader that the operation modifies the state of `ObjHandler`.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks for the feedback. Improved the answer.

Answer (score 10):

The `unique` means actually 'unique ownership'.  It makes no sense that you would create a copy of the ownership, since then it would not be unique anymore.

What you probably want is returning a *reference* to the contained object, or a *non owning* pointer:

```
class ObjHandler {
   Object &get(){ return *obj; }
   Object *GetPtr() { return obj.get(); }
private:
   unique_ptr<Object> obj;
};
```

[This post](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) is a very good talk on the what/where/why of using smart pointers.

And the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-ptr) have a hint on this, too: a raw pointer is by definition indication of the fact that the object is not owned.

Comment: _a raw pointer is by definition indication of the fact that the object is not owned_ ... which may or may not be true if you work with legacy C++ code or interface with C code, where you often have *owning* raw pointers which are returned to you with the expectation that you deallocate them by yourself. An example is the Windows API.